# Selector ":root" is not pure NextJS error saas loader

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

Anyone have seen the error before ?

**Selector ":root [data-theme]" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)**

```
 :root [data-theme] {

 }
```

Can I disable this stylelint eror ?

Comment: Is this inside a `.module` file? If this is meant to be a global style, you should move it to a global stylesheet and import it in `_app` instead. If it's not global, then you need to scope it properly.